# Can Rails schema table be outside the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

We have a legacy PostgreSQL database that is perfectly accessible from a Rails app except that when the vendor provides an update one of the consistency checks they perform against the database fails because Rails has built a "new" table there, the schema migrations table.  Is it possible to direct creation of this table elsewhere? Or is it possible to use the schema cache in Rails 4 to effect this? The [release notes](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html) section 3.3 on General things says "Schema cache dump (commit) - To improve Rails boot time, instead of loading the schema directly from the database, load the schema from a dump file."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an old blog post about this last time I tried it [here](http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/schema-cache-dump-rails-4-countdown-to-2013). Copying the relevant parts:

To make a dump of your schema, execute the following rake task:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:schema:cache:dump
```

This will generate a file `db/schema_cache.dump`, that Rails will use to load the internal state of the SchemaCache instance.

To disable the schema cache dump, add the following to your `config/production.rb` file:

```
config.active_record.use_schema_cache_dump = false
```

If you would like to clear the schema cache, execute:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:schema:cache:clear
```